# Material-ui & TouchTap: Getting key of ListItem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a list of items using material-ui. I would like to call _handleTouchTap() when the item is clicked and pass the key of the ListItem to the handler.

Adding

```
onTouchTap={this._handleTouchTap}
```

to  is not working as 'this' seems the be the wrong scope

```
var React = require('react');
var Mui = require('material-ui');
var ThemeManager = new Mui.Styles.ThemeManager();
ThemeManager.setTheme(ThemeManager.types.LIGHT);
var injectTapEventPlugin = require('react-tap-event-plugin');
injectTapEventPlugin();
var List = Mui.List
var ListItem = Mui.ListItem

var Main = React.createClass({
  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  },
  getChildContext: function () {
    return {
      muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    var items = [
      {id: 1, title: 'Item 1'},
      {id: 2, title: 'Item 2'},
      {id: 3, title: 'Item 3'}
    ]
    return (
        <List>
          {items.map(function(item){
            return <ListItem key={item.id} primaryText={item.title} />
          })}
        </List>
    )
  },

  _handleTouchTap: function() {
    // the key of the item should be passed though here
  }
});

React.render(<Main />, document.body);
```

Comment: Use id instead of key in the event handler. Just add id={item.id} to your ListItem. Then event.target.id returns the id.

Answer (score 7):

If `event.target.id` isn't working due to concerns that Tim Welch pointed out above, you can simply pass the item ID as a parameter to your handler function

```
render: function() {
        var items = [
          {id: 1, title: 'Item 1'},
          {id: 2, title: 'Item 2'},
          {id: 3, title: 'Item 3'}
        ]
        return (
            <List>
              {items.map(function(item){
                return <ListItem key={item.id} 
                                 primaryText={item.title} 
                                 onTouchTap={this._handleTouchTap.bind(this, item.id)}/>
              })}
            </List>
        )
      },

      _handleTouchTap: function(id) {
        console.log(id) // Logs item id
      }
});
```

Instead of using `onTouchTap={this._handleTouchTap.bind(this, item.id)}`, if you're using es6 you can instead use an es6 fat arrow function which will automatically bind `this` for you. It can be done like this: 
`onTouchTap={() => this._handleTouchTap(item.id)}`

Comment: Does not work for me... _handleTouchTap is directly executes for each element of items.

Comment: @Sucrenoir Check my edited answer above. Make sure you're binding `this` either with `bind()` or the use of an es6 fat arrow function if you're using es6.

Comment: It works, but only with onClick :-) Not very readable tough... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Sharing what I learned. Take a look at the [MakeSelectable](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list) higher-order component that Material-UI offers for creating a selectable List that gives you the index of the currently selected item onChange.  This might be new since the question was asked.  Note the value attribute on the ListItem's below and the onChange event on the SelectableList.

```
import {List, ListItem, MakeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List'
SelectableList = MakeSelectable(List)

const siteItems = Object.keys(sites || {}).map((index) => {
  const site = sites[index]
  return (<ListItem
    key={index + 1}
    value={site.id}
    leftAvatar={<Avatar icon={<PinDrop />} />}
    primaryText={site.name}
    secondaryText={site.description}
    style={styles.list}
  />)
})
CurList = (
  <div style={styles.listcontainer}>
    <SelectableList onChange={this.siteSelected}>
      {siteItems}
    </SelectableList>
  </div>
)
```

The problem I found with pattern of setting the id of the listitem and trying to access it via event.target.id is that event.target will vary if you have sub-elements in your List item like icons, labels, etc. which most of the List examples have.

Comment: Setting the id into value prop does the trick for me. Thx Tim.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the newer ES6 class syntax and arrow function, this could be the answer. You need to explicitly bind the `this` keyword if you are using class syntax to correctly specify the `this` context. `onTouchTap` expects a method, so I'm returning a function using ES6 arrow function.

```
import { Component, React } from 'react';
import { List, ListItem } from 'material-ui/List';
class Main extends Component {

   constructor() {
      super(...arguments);
      this._handleTouchTap = this._handleTouchTap.bind(this);
   }

   _handleTouchTap(id) {
       return () => console.log(id) // Logs item id
   }

   render () {        
      var items = [
         {id: 1, title: 'Item 1'},
         {id: 2, title: 'Item 2'},
         {id: 3, title: 'Item 3'}
       ];

       return (
           <List>
             {items.map(function(item){
               return (
                  <ListItem 
                     key={item.id} 
                     primaryText={item.title} 
                     onTouchTap={this._handleTouchTap(item.id)}
                   />
                )
             })}
           </List>
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can achieve the same binding by simply doing `onTouchTap={() => this._handleTouchTap(item.id)}` without explicitly binding `this` in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the listitem onTouchTap prop and set event to handleTouchTap parameter

```
<ListItem onTouchTap={this._handleTouchTap} />

_handleTouchTap: function(event){
  var clickedID = event.target.id
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  ```id``` doesn't seem to be set in v0.15.0 beta 2.